# How do you select a record that has 4 digits/characters in a specific field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select all records where there are only 4 digits in a specific field.

I'm using SQL Server.  The WHERE condition is looking at a character field that contains numbers.  I want to select all the records where this field only has 4 numbers.

```
SELECT * FROM Server.database.schema.table
WHERE ci_dnis [has 4 characters]
```

Answer (score 2):

If `ci_dnis` has integer data type you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM Server.database.schema.table WHERE ci_dnis BETWEEN 1000 AND 9999;
```

Otherwise:

```
SELECT * FROM Server.database.schema.table WHERE LEN(ci_dnis) = 4;
```

Comment: ci_dnis has a character data type, so that second one worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want four digits, then:

```
WHERE ci_dnis LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

Or:

```
WHEN LEN(ci_dnis) = 4 AND           -- has a length of 4
     ci_dnis NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'    -- has no non-digits
```